# Equivalent of #ifdef in VHDL for simulation/synthesis separation?

Tags: vhdl

In order to ease the visual reading of simulation waves, I would like to assign some signals to "XXXX", but only at simulation time, and thus I want the logical synthesis tool (ISE in my case) to skip those instructions.

Two questions from here:

1. Is there an equivalent technique of a #ifdef SIMULATION_TIME, like in C ?
2. Would an assignment to "XXXX" have any influence on the logical synthesis (reset to 0 ? warnings ? nothing ?). If it has no impact at all, then my question is answered. If not, I still need to assign to "XXXX"...

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain to us why you want to assign "X" values to your signals? Seems highly exceptional. Note that things like if(a='X') will not work in synthesized code!

Comment: I think it's quite common to assign signals with `X` in order to easily see when a signal changes for the first time. Additionaly, you can recognize critical results that stem from your `X` signal. If you assign your signal to `0` by default, your results may look reasonable at the first glance.

Comment: "In order to ease the visual reading of simulation waves". I just want to prettify my wave outputs, for screenshot insertion in articles. I know it won't work in synthesized code, that's why I wrote this question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(1) You're looking for

```
--pragma synthesis_off
  -- your simulation-only code
--pragma synthesis_on
```

(2) You might get some warnings from ISE, especially when these signals drive logic. Just make sure, that the signals have a defined value before you use them. This method should work then, as well.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, pragmas are not really standardized, but the most common ones are "-- pragma synthesis_on/off", "-- pragma translate_on/off", and same thing by replacing "pragma" with "synopsys".

Answer (score 8):

If you find yourself wanting to use ifdef for arbitrary code selection then you can use the VHDL keywords **if generate**.

```
label: if SOME_OPTION = SOME_VALUE generate
  some VHDL here
end generate;
```

This is handy if you need to optionally include some code, however the *synthesis on/off* is more widely used if the selection is between simulation and synthesis.

Comment: Yep, and also if I just need to "disable" a single assignment in a 300+ lines process, instead of writing two versions of the process and using generate. But +1 for that, that's nice to remember this feature !

Comment: I think ```ìf-generate``` cannot be used in processes. What should be the case if we are trying to enable/disable code snippet which is inside a process?

Answer (score 8):

One other trick to go with George's answer - if you want a boolean for `in_synthesis` say:

```
constant in_simulation : boolean := false
--pragma synthesis_off
                                    or true
--pragma synthesis_on
;
constant in_synthesis : boolean := not in_simulation;
```

Comment: Yep, nice trick. I wonder however if synthesizers are smart enough to remove an "if (true)" from the logic code :) (well, I bet they are, but sometimes you just wonder...)

Comment: In my experience they certainly are :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, there is typically a way to turn off synthesis that is tool dependent (check the ISE docs).

When I need something more sophisticated, I perform pre-processing.  Typically, I use makefiles and various *nix flavored text processing tools (sed, awk, perl, &c).  This can be as simple or as complex as desired.  What started as a way to uncomment different blocks of code for simulation vs. synthesis now extracts register documentation and auto-generates C header files for the SW team.

If you don't want to "roll you own", you can apply one of the many pre-existing implementations (C pre-processer, m4 macro language, &c) to your build process.